# Notification system like facebook and real time

Tags: php, real-time

I'm working on a notification system like facebook and now i want to add a real time system.

I am on a custom MVC model, so in my controller i call a class `Notification()` and i retrieve all new notifications. (i put them in php variable)

After that, i include my view and in this view i do some treatments for change color of my notification (red or normal), change the number etc...

Now i need to add a real time system, how can i do that simply ?

For example i need to call a php function `getNewNotif()` and if this method return something different than 0, i need to refresh my div with new data...

Comment: Anything done in realtime should realistically use websockets. Look it up. If websockets aren't an option then you can use long-polling with ajax.

Comment: If i use html5 websocket ? It's ok ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many approaches. Starting from doing an ajax call every few seconds (dont do it!) to sockets (which is by far the better approach). You might want to take a look at  [JAXL](https://github.com/abhinavsingh/JAXL)

Or write your own implementation via (web)sockets

Answer (score 0):

You can try PHP WebSocket Class
https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/